# Add referer header in Exoplayer2 Android

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I need s small change in my exoplayer app to play m3u8 url with referer. Since i  new in java programming, i still confused how to add the header. Here is part of my code . Thanks in advance

```
 private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
        return buildDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter ? BANDWIDTH_METER : null);
    }

    public DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {
        return new DefaultDataSourceFactory(requireActivity(), bandwidthMeter,
                buildHttpDataSourceFactory(bandwidthMeter));
    }

    public HttpDataSource.Factory buildHttpDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {
        return new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(isUserAgent ? userAgentName : Util.getUserAgent(requireActivity(), "ExoPlayerDemo"), bandwidthMeter);

    }
```

I have tried this but give some red line error

```
    public HttpDataSource.Factory buildHttpDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {
        return new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(isUserAgent ? userAgentName : Util.getUserAgent(requireActivity(), "ExoPlayerDemo"), bandwidthMeter).getDefaultRequestProperties().set("referer","myrefererer");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code will helps you:

```
private HttpDataSource.Factory buildHttpDataSourceFactory() {
        Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap();
        settings.put("Referer", "my_referer_value");
        return new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
                .setUserAgent(Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "your agent"))
                .setDefaultRequestProperties(settings)
                .setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true);
    }
```